# Elementary question: Cubic 4-fold and rational quartic scroll

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Forgive me to ask an elementary question, because I really need the answer to this today (I already asked this in Stackexchange.)

Let $S$ be the rational quartic scroll in $\mathbb{P}^5$ ($S$ is the image of the embedding $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^5$ via $|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1}(1,2)|$).

> 1/ Why does every point on $\mathbb{P}^5$ lie on a unique secant line or tangent line to $S$?
>
> 2/ Suppose a cubic fourfold $X\subset \mathbb{P}^5$ contains $S$. Why does $X$ necessarily contain two skewed 2-planes?

It's fine if you just leave me a reference. Thank you very much.

Comment: 2/ is false. For a cubic fourfold $X$, let $\rho $ denote the rank of $H^4(X,\mathbb{Z})_{\mathrm{alg}}$. A general cubic fourfold containing $S$ will have $\rho =2$, while cubics containing two skew planes have $\rho =3$.

Comment: According to the atlas that Joe Harris produced, it appears that if a cubic fourfold $X$ contains a quartic scroll $\Sigma$, then the residual to $\Sigma$ in the intersection of $X$ with a Segre cubic threefold $Y$ is either a quintic del Pezzo surface or a quintic scroll.  Presumably the difference is whether the quintic rational normal curve whose secant variety equals $Y$ sits in $\Sigma$ as a curve with self-intersection number $4$ or $6$.

Comment: By Beauville and Donagi, a cubic fourfold that contains a quintic del Pezzo surface is Pfaffian: Beauville, Arnaud; Donagi, Ron;
La variété des droites d'une hypersurface cubique de dimension 4,
C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. I Math. 301 (1985), no. 14, 703–706.  Please see the following MO question for an explanation why every $X$ containing a quartic scroll contains a quintic del Pezzo: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78228/are-cubic-four-folds-containing-a-quartic-scroll-pfaffians

Comment: I may have misattributed the result about Pfaffian cubic fourfolds being precisely those that contain a quintic del Pezzo surface.  According to the MO answer that I linked, it appears the following is the correct citation:  Arnaud Beauville; Determinantal Hypersurfaces. Michigan Math. J. 48, 2000.

Comment: Thank you very much. One question: Does a cubic 4-fold containing two skewed planes lie in the class $\mathcal{C}_{14}$ just like a cubic 4-fold containing a quartic scroll ($\mathcal{C}_{14}$ are the cubic 4-folds having a discriminant-$14$ lattice in the sense of Hassett)?

Comment: Yes a cubic 4-fold containing 2 skewed planes lies in $\mathcal C_{14}$.  You can see that the virtual class of a quartic scroll is $2h^2-P_1-P_2$ where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are skew planes.  So such a cubic fourfold contains the usual rank 2 sublattice of discriminant 14 associated with containing a quartic scroll.

Comment: Above when I wrote "Segre cubic threefold", I should have written "image of $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^2$ under a Segre embedding".  The atlas just says "Segre threefold". Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question about secant lines reduces to a Chern class computation on the blowing up $\nu:\widetilde{\Sigma \times \Sigma}\to \Sigma \times \Sigma$ along the diagonal, where $\Sigma$ is the <del>cubic</del> quartic scroll.  Your claim is equivalent to the assertion that in $A^4(\widetilde{\Sigma \times \Sigma})$, the following class equals $2$ (overcounting by $2$, because the pair of points is ordered). $$2 = a^4 - 3a^2 b + b^2,\ \ a = \nu^*\text{pr}_1^*c_1(\mathcal{O}(1)) + \nu^*\text{pr}_2^*c_1(\mathcal{O}(1)) - i_*(1),$$ $$b = \nu^*\left( \text{pr}_1^*c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))\cdot \text{pr}_2^*c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))\right) - i_*\pi^*c_1(\mathcal{O}(1)) $$ where $i:E\to \widetilde{\Sigma\times \Sigma}$ is the exceptional divisor, where $\pi:E\to \Sigma$ is the projection to the diagonal, and where $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is the usual Serre twisting sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^5$.  I have not computed whether or not $a^4-3a^2b+b^2$ does indeed equal $2$ . . .

**Edit.** The computation by abx seems more robust, since it is not vulnerable to arithmetic mistakes.  Nonetheless, I just got back to the Chern class computation.  I compute that $a^4$ equals $44$, $a^2b$ equals $18$ and $b^2$ equals $12$.  Thus $a^4-3a^2b+b^2$ equals $44-3(18)+12$.  This does equal $2$, as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another (sketch of) proof of 1). Let $V$ be a 2-dimensional vector space; you can view your scroll as the image of the embedding $\mathbb{P}(V)\times \mathbb{P}(V)\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(V\otimes \mathsf{S}^2V)$ given by $(v,w)\mapsto v\otimes w^2$.  Let $p$ be an element of  $\mathbb{P}(V\otimes \mathsf{S}^2V) \smallsetminus S$; it can be written  $v_1\otimes t_1+v_2\otimes t_2$. The line $\langle t_1,t_2\rangle$ in $\mathbb{P}(\mathsf{S}^2V)$ is determined by $p$; it contains  2 rank 1 tensors $w_1^2$ and $w_2^2$ (up to scalar), given by the intersection of  $\langle t_1,t_2\rangle$ with the conic of rank 1 tensors. Thus $p$ can be written $v'_1\otimes w_1^2+v'_2\otimes w_2^2$, where the points $(v'_1,w_1)$ and $(v'_2,w_2)$ of $\mathbb{P}(V)\times \mathbb{P}(V)$ are uniquely determined, and span the unique secant line passing through $p$.